# Generate Functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I have two functions

```
"This is my docstring for `add_1(x)`"
add_1(x) = x + 1

"This is my docstring for `add_2(x)`"
add_2(x) = x + 2
```

The code of the two functions is strikingly similar, so that in Julia there must be a clever way of automating their creation.

Side question: If these functions were generated programmatically, how would errors work out? Usually the stack trace shows a line number in the originating file, but here several functions are generated from the same line. Would it always show the same line number as well?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be this

```
["""
"This is my docstring for \`add_$i(x)\`"
add_$i(x) = x + $i
""" for i ∈ 1:3] .|> Meta.parse .|> eval
```

Regarding the line numbers, however, I am stuck. This is what you get by deliberately causing an error:

```
julia> add_3("arstoen")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::String, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:560
  +(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16,         UInt32, UInt64, UInt8} at int.jl:87
  +(::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Number) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/uniformscaling.jl:145
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] add_3(x::String)
   @ Main ./none:2
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

Does anyone else know a way of making the stacktrace sensible?

Comment: I would recommend moving this as a part of your question as you are actually asking how to inject the line number information into a generated code.

Comment: The normal way to do this is `for i in 1:3; fn = Symbol(:add_, i); @eval $fn(x) = x + $i; end`, which should get line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually built abstract syntax tree (AST) of the code and inject appropriate `LineNumberNode`s.

Let's start with some AST. It is usually easiest to have Julia generate the initial AST at the beginning and than mutate it.

```
code = quote
  add_1(x) = x+1
end
```

Try running `dump(code)` to see the AST (I omit it here as the output is long).

Now we can mutate it to generate `add_2`. You can put the code below in a function and generate is many variants of `add_n` as you want but for readability I will focus just on `add_2`.

```
code.args[1] = LineNumberNode(2, Symbol("My line of add_2"))
code.args[2].args[1] = :(add_2(x))
code.args[2].args[2].args[1] =  LineNumberNode(2, Symbol("My function body of add two"))
code.args[2].args[2].args[2].args[3]=2
```

That's it! You have your custom function with custom line numbering. Let's test it!

```
julia> eval(code)
add_2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> add_2(4)
6

julia> add_2("will errror")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::String, ::Int64)
  [...]
Stacktrace:
 [1] add_2(x::String)
   @ Main .\My function body of add two:2
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[22]:1
```

You can see that you can inject any location information in your generated code as you want.

For further reading have a look at: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/ast/

Comment: And specifically, you could inject information based on [`@__LINE__` and `@__FILE__`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Macro-invocation).